# Preventing Infinite Calls to the API in Angular App Conditional Logic

Tags: angular

I am trying to understand why some logic I have in my Angular app is causing an infinite call on the API. And what's that's clear, I want to determine a better way to do this.

First off, in my view I have some validation on a button that looks like this:

```
<button md-button (click)="completeCategory()" 
  [disabled]="!canComplete()"
  [class.button-disabled]="!canComplete()">Complete
</button>
```

Now, as part of that validation in my component, I make a call to the API to check on some data:

```
public async isDocSigned() {
    const customerId = this.customer._id;
    const type = 'catOrig';
    const response: any = await this.stageService.checkSignedDoc(customerId, type);

    // Look for errors
    if (!response || response.ok !== true)
    {
        let message = 'Failed to obtain signature data';
        console.error(message, response);
        return;
    }

    if (response && response.count > 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (response && response.count < 1) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

By the way, the service function called above looks like this:

```
public async checkCustomerSigned(customerId, type) {
    return await API.service.send({
        reqType: 'get',
        req: `customers/validation/ptlDocument`,
        reqArgs: { customer: customerId, type: type }
    });
}
```

And I use that returned API response as part of my conditional logic to see if the button with the `canComplete()` button should be enabled.

Two conditional factors are taken into consideration. 1.) Is the doc in the correct stage, and 2.) if s, is the doc signed:

```
public async canComplete() {
    if (this.selectedService.category['stage'] === 'awaiting signature from customer') {
        const docSigned = await this.isDocSigned();
        if (docSigned) return true;
        if (!docSigned) return false;
    }
}
```

So, from testing this code, it becomes clear that the `isDocSigned()` function makes calls to the API over and over again.

I assume this is because Angular sees the button with the `canComplete()` function in the view, and then constantly evaluates it?

What I end up seeing, when the doc is in this stage, is this console.log line printing over and over again to the screen:

```
`console.error(message, response);`
```

So what is a better way to handle this? Should I put `isDocSigned()` in the constructor, or within a life cycle hook like `ngOninit()`? How can I resolve the infinite call here? Ideally, I just want to make this API call once. I'd really appreciate an example of how to do this. A simple stackBlitz example would be really helpful.

Comment: use a field _isDocSigned to store the status, `if(this._isDocSigned !== undefined) return this._isDocSigned; else this._isDocSigned  = await this.isDocSigned();.... your old logic`

Comment: Thanks. Could you add this in an answer so I can see the code a little more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the reason why your API is getting called in due to Angular Change Detection. In your HTML file you are calling a function and Angular does not know if the return type of the function has changed. Hence it keeps executing the function which is causing the infinite API calls. Below is the faulty code:

```
[class.button-disabled]="!canComplete()"
```

It is highly discouraged to use functions in templates. This can be change to use something like this:

```
[class.button-disabled]="!docSigned"
```

and moving canComplete() method to ngOnInint. Note that this will limit the call to API only on page load.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful for clarifying what the issue is.

Answer (score -1):

```
public async canComplete() {
  if (this.selectedService.category['stage'] === 'awaiting signature from customer') {
    if(this._docSigned !== undefined) {
      return this._docSigned;
    } 
    return this._docSigned = await this.isDocSigned();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Trying this now.

Comment: @Muirik, this above approach just cached the API result, so it won't call API again

Comment: I'm confused here. So the first function isDocSigned() needs to return TRUE or FALSE so that I can apply that result as one of the two boolean checks I do the canComplete() function before ultimately returning TRUE or FALSE for it. So can you include what the isDocSigned() function should look like as well. Also, are you saying I initialize a variable called `isDocSigned` and initially set it to `undefined`: `isDocSigned = undefined;

Comment: Okay, and what about initializing a variable in the component. Should that be `isDocSigned = undefined` ?

Comment: by default, it is undefined.

Comment: you can also check function, since it returns variable as well.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show the initializing of the variable, and the two functions, as well as what should be in the HTML. Just want to make sure I'm clear here. I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: In the `canComplete()` function, that function needs to return `true` if this._docSigned is no longer `undefined`. Doesn't it? That's what allows the button to be enabled, if `canComplete()` ultimately returns `true`.

Comment: `canComplete()` needs to return a boolean value of `true` or `false` to enable/disable the button.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue. The API still gets called infinitely.

Comment: if you can provide a stackblitz, I can take a look, since I don't know what you did on your side.